# Why is IE6 not rendering this border properly?

Tags: html, css, border, internet-explorer-6

I am currently finishing a site that the client wants to work on all browsers. However, there seems to be a CSS issue which I can not get around. The border around this page seems to start from the middle of the page, as opposed to surrounding the entire page. It works on all other browsers though. I am guessing that it is a float problem, but the `#contact-form` underneath has basically the same CSS applied to it but the border still surrounds it, while the `#info` seems to have broken out of the border.

The webpage in question is http://lunaskymoda.co.uk/contact-us/

The only validation error is with an unregistered keyword "Nextgen", but i doubt that is the problem. I have spent an entire day tackling this and cannot seem to come up with a reasonable explanation as to why this is happening.

the CSS for the possible HTML elements producing the error are:

```
#main #main-content {
border: 1px solid white;
display: block;
margin: 12px 0;
background: black;
}

.contact #main-content .info {
margin: 10px;
width: 300px;
font-size: 14px;
color: white;
float: right;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Found a few errors in Console of Webkit Chrome

Comment: @Xavier that seems to be a JavaScript problem that's not affecting any of the other pages. I'm pretty sure this is a CSS issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not the first one to have issues with ie6 :)
The problem is of course the "clear: both" of the clear class not being honoured, so you need to hack it.
Here's a possible approach:
http://damienhowley.wordpress.com/2009/04/01/ie6-hack-replacing-clearboth/
You may also try to replace the <div class="clear"></div> by <br clear="all">.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was scared that I had done something wrong, turns out it is indeed an IE6 bug. The article helped a lot! Cheers!